Breeze Sharp - does it support a change set involving multiple instances of the same entity?
Breeze.sharp 0.9.8, Blazor .NET 7 and EF Core.
I have a model, Lines, with a scalar navigation property, Item.
The model has a primary key comprising 7 properties and 3 of those properties make up a foreign key used when relating to the Item entity.
I retrieve a list of Lines via a Breeze query and multiple entities have the same 3 foreign key properties and thus should reference the same Item entity.
Two problems arise though :

only one of these Line entities that should have the same Item actually have Item populated, the other Line entities have null (all other entities that do not share an Item are fine)
saving changes to the list results in this error :
"System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'Line' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{BomHeaderID: 0-6                           , Revision:           , Type: product   }' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'"


BomHeaderID, Revision and Type are the three foreign keys relating to Item.

If the list of Lines only contains entities that do not share an Item then they all save successfully, but if even one double-up is present then entityManager.SaveChanges() fails.
The Item entity has no changes made to it, only basic properties on Line are changed.
The error still occurs even if I don't expand the Item property or detach the Item entities after fetching!
I can make the save work by calling SaveChanges(new IEntity[] {thisRow}) one by one for each row in the Lines list, but this is a nasty hack to avoid using the same dbContext for all commits.
I realise this is an entity framework core error, but I am assuming something is going wrong with Breeze (perhaps in its JSON serialisation to the server?).
Any ideas welcome...
BTW, could someone explain to me where I should be getting the latest version of Breeze.Sharp from?
Nuget has version 0.9.8, while https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.sharp has 0.8.1 !!
Where is 0.9.8 coming from?
(Similar question for the other Breeze libraries, the version noted in the github repo doesn't always match the one in Nuget).
[Edit] Nuget does not have 0.9.8, the original BlazorBoilerPlate Blazor project does, from somewhere.
Breeze.Sharp from "breeze.github.io"

Breeze.Sharp.Standard.Fork, from nuget

[Edit]
Not exactly an answer, but to mitigate the problems I did two things :

since the dbContext is only used later by Breeze and it has its own tracking system, I added AsNoTracking to the entire context - this fixed the missing duplicate child entities
when saving in a scenario where there could be duplicate children, I have to save row by row instead of doing it all in one call


7 properties in the primary key is... a lot.  Have you inspected the Breeze metadata to see if it is representing the primary key and foreign key correctly?
In Nuget, I see Breeze.Sharp with version 0.8.2: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Breeze.Sharp.  Where do you see 0.9.8?

What is the simplest way to inspect the metadata?
I have checked the various properties in the EntityAspect of the entities and they all look fine with primary and foreign keys.
I have added a screen shot of the nuget details.

Usually there is an HttpGet Metadata() endpoint on a Breeze controller that returns the metadata as JSON.  I still can't find this 0.9.8 version of Breeze.Sharp.  Is it on nuget.org, or some other package source?  What is the release date?

I am developing a project based on https://github.com/enkodellc/blazorboilerplate and I see now that the version of Breeze.Sharp included with the project is derived from http://breeze.github.io (21 Oct 2020), whatever that really means; screenshot added above.
The later versions of the project have migrated to Breeze.Sharp.Standard.Fork and I have now moved to that also, as it contains bug fixes necessary for the base project.

...bug fixes that are not present in Breeze.Sharp on nuget

I have looked at the JSON metadata and it looks fine.  This is a complicated scenario, with Lines actually being a TPH child of a base model and only the Lines child having the navigation to Item; but it all works well except when there is a duplicate Item child navigation in the save-set.

It seems like EF (and thus Breeze) does not understand that Line inherits part of its key from its base model.  The InvalidOperationException you posted above seems to indicate that EF thinks only 3 fields are part of the key.

At first that would seem to be the cause, but EF does understand it because I can see the full key being used in the SQL updates.
Hence I think something is awry with the the three foreign keys for the relation to the child type Item, which will sometimes point to the same entity.
Sometimes I can get this error being reported from SaveChanges() -
"Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'."

Perhaps you could try to recreate the situation in C# + EF code only.  Write a C# method that saves three Lines with the same Item.

I confirm that with EF only, the problem of the missing Item entities still happens but SaveChanges() is fine with "duplicate foreign keys" (or whatever it is really upset about), all entities are updated.

On another note, do you think Breeze.Sharp could incorporate the changes being made in Breeze.Standard.Fork?
Looks like PR 44 contains a number of them.
Would be nice to have an official repo that contains all changes.

Yes, I'll get those fixes incorporated into the main Breeze.Sharp.
